# email questions

Tags: apex, email, massemailmessage

i want to email our internal users (200+) with a link to a custom object, but single email doesnt send to enough people and mass email cant set an object id to a custom object. is there a way to bulk email but set the html body, or something..?? or do i have to batch execute the single email process?

i have tried both sending single email; which works for 10 emails, and ive tried mass email but the custom object id doesnt come through.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Outlook mail merge feature. It allows to send mass emails and insert Salesforce fields in the body of an email. You can read more about Outlook's mail merge feature [here](http://help.contactmonkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/200809566-Does-ContactMonkey-work-with-Outlook-Mail-Merge-)